# How do I add a feed for a tag in a chat room?

Tags: support, chat, feed

If I want, say, all [lord-of-the-rings] posts from scifi.SE to go to my chat room, what do I do in the add feed bit? What URL do I paste there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [tag page itself](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings); there will be a feed icon in the bottom right-hand corner:

[image: RSS icon for lord-of-the-rings on SciFi]

Right-click on that icon and select `Copy Link` to get a feed you can add to your chat room. The link will look something like this:

```
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=lord-of-the-rings&sort=newest
```